# context.Request.Files collection empty on remote server only

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, ashx

I'm using a custom ashx handler to handle a file upload. When run locally, the file uploads fine.
When I use the same setup on the web server I get a `"Index out of range"` error.
In firebug I see the binary contents of the file in the post data and the file name is also passed in the query string.
Any one seen this before?
I`m sure its something minor, but its driving me up the wall.

**Update:** Made some progress. I found out that I'm getting two different errors. One from FF / Chrome and one from IE. I'm focusing on FF now, just because firebug makes debugging easier. Now I get an error "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\'"

**Update 2:** Got this working in FF/Chrome. Turns out IE and FF/Chrome post the data differentlly.

**Update 3:** Here is the output of the network profiler in IE dev tool:

```
Request header:
Key Value
Request POST /Secured/UploadHandler.ashx? HTTP/1.1
Accept  text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer http://cms.webstreet.co.il/Secured/fileUpload.aspx
Accept-Language he-IL
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7db13b13d1b12
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    cms.webstreet.co.il
Content-Length  262854
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache

Request body:
-----------------------------7db13b13d1b12
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="P-Art_Page_Digital.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<Binary File Data Not Shown>
---------------------------7db13b13d1b12--
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code?  I have had some problems similar to this, and I think mine related to differences between path mapping in Cassini and IIS.

Comment: I considered that, but then I used an absolute path on the remote file system and it didn't work either. I could try a local iis, but i'll get to that only tomorrow.

Comment: Your not by any chance saving the file using `Request.Files[0].FileName` property, are you? Older versions of IE actually sent the entire path to the file (`c:\folder.image.jpg`) instead of just the name (`image.jpg`)

Comment: Nope. The file collection is empty. Request.Files[0] = null.

Comment: Anyone know if there was a change in AJAX behavior between IE8 and IE9? Maybe that's where the problem is.

Comment: you seem to report unrelated issues. Index Out Of range is because Request.Files is empty, File Not Found is another, and what is this "Save As" IE command about? This is client only, not related to server actions. Please update your text with the exact issue, and possibly some details (stackframe for example) and code.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Just updated the post to remove all confusion. My problem is still that the .Files collection is empty. Nothing has changed. And I get the error on the server-side, inside the ASHX.

Comment: @Elad - are you sure the html 'form' tag declares the proper 'enctype' attribute? you need to set it to enctype="multipart/form-data" I believe.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: but that gave me an idea. I catured the request in the IE dev tool. Updated post with data.

Comment: I don't really know what to make of it, but maybe someone here can analyze this.

Comment: @Elad - ok, it clearly shows you **do have** a file coming in. Have you checked Chris Haas comment? Are you still having the Request.Files.Count at 0, or the path error with this file coming in?

Comment: The Files.Count is still 0. The path error was on the way to getting the FF/Chrome version working.

Comment: @Elad - If the server file count is still 0 while there is a multi-part posted file, it means something messes with the request on the server side. Have you checked HttpModules, HttpHandlers, Redirects? (PS: when you reply to comments you should use @+nickname so we know you are sending message)

Comment: @Simon Mourier - I checked, nothing I can see. There are no redirects. Come to think of it, the file initiating the upload is in a formsauthentication secured directory. Could that mess with the post?

Comment: @Simon Mourier - tried moving the aspx and ashx files outside the secured folder and still no joy.

Comment: @Elad - Can you check on the server Request.ContentType is well set to 'multipart/form-data'? And one last thing: since, your code is running in an ASHX, maybe ASP.NET cannot populate the Files collection because it's too early, or it has not enough info. If you direct the upload to an ASPX instead, is the Request.Files still empty?

Comment: @Simon Mourier - ContentType is set in code and verified in the request itself (as you can see in the last post update). I have not considered using an ASPX file. I used ashx, since it was the example I was given. What are the pros/cons of using aspx to handle the upload, as opposed to ashx?

Comment: @Elad - Request Content Type should no be set in code, as it **must** be 'multipart/form-data' for ASP.NET to fill the Files collection. Concerning ASPX vs ASHX, I think it's just worth a try.

Comment: @Simon Mourier - Where should it be set? Not in the asp.net form tag? Can you point me to a resource on implementing an ajax file upload handler in an aspx file?

Comment: @Simon Mourier - It works! For some reason the file name was not posted in .Files[0].Filename. Don't know why. I just took the filename from Request["qqfile"] and it works! I still don't know why the Files.Count shows zero, but the file is now being saved. Please post an answer with your comments and I'll award you the bounty for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the (big) list of comments and replies attached to the original question. Not sure why it works now, but Elad seems to have fixed his problem.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Without your comments I would have never focused my attention in the right places.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the name tag.

```
<input id="File1" name="file1" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure file uploads CANNOT be done via Ajax; you need to use a regular form post.

Also make sure you have the enctype attribute set correctly on your form tag.

Comment: Yes they can. It works in ff/chrome. IE is the problem. Encrypt Attribute? Please elaborate.

Comment: Oh really, interesting, thought it wasn't possible.

Check out http://www.15seconds.com/issue/001003.htm which mentions the 'enctype' (not encrypt, but 'encode type') attribute of form tags.

Comment: It is. I'm using it as we speak :) Oh... I see. Ya, I miss-read that. It's already set.